# Flutter Dropdown UI

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using the below code but not able to achieve the desired result, I am new to the flutter world so let me know where to improve to get the desired result. Here is the source code of what I have done.

```
return LoadingIndicatorPage(
  loading: _loading,
  child: Scaffold(
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.brown,
        image: new DecorationImage(
          image: new ExactAssetImage("graphics/register_bg.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: LEFTRIGHT_PADDING, right: LEFTRIGHT_PADDING),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _currentOpacity,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Text(
                      AppLocalizations.of(context).registerTitle,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context).registerNameHint,
                        style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFieldInput(
                    inputType: TextInputType.text,
                    textEditingController: nameController,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)
                            .registerPhoneNumberHint,
                        style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFieldInput(
                    inputType: TextInputType.text,
                    textEditingController: phoneNumberController,
                  ),


                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        'Country',
                        style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),




                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(
                        color: shadow,
                        blurRadius: 4.0,
                        offset: Offset(1.0, 4.0),
                      )],
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(5.0)
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        alignedDropdown: true,
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: _selectedItem,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                          hint: Text('Select Country'),
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedItem = newValue;
                              print(_selectedItem);
                            });
                          },
                          items: countryList?.map((item) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new Text(item.name),
                              value: item.id.toString(),
                            );
                          })?.toList() ??
                              [],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ),





                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context).registerEmailHint,
                        style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFieldInput(
                    inputType: TextInputType.text,
                    textEditingController: emailController,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context).registerPasswordHint,
                        style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  TextFieldInput(
                    inputType: TextInputType.text,
                    textEditingController: passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: INPUT_FIELDS_SPACING),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.of(context)
                            .registerRepeatPasswordHint,
                        style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFieldInput(
                    inputType: TextInputType.text,
                    textEditingController: repeatPasswordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
                    child: Button(
                        text: AppLocalizations.of(context).registerRegister,
                        buttonOnPressed: _createAccount),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 15.0, 8.0, 0),
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 1,
                      color: whiteTwo,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 30),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text:
                              AppLocalizations.of(context).registerLoginPre,
                          style: TextStyle(color: brownishGrey),
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                              text: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                  .registerLoginPost,
                              style: TextStyle(color: purpleishBlueThree),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

ISSUE: The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 154 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
DropdownButton

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally what happens is whenever the child wants to get rendered it asks its parents to provide the height and width. Now the width of the container is restricted due to padding from the both sides So the child is overflowing

Now what you can tell the child is to be flexible so wrap the container child with `Flexible(),` widget

like this

```
Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(
                        color: shadow,
                        blurRadius: 4.0,
                        offset: Offset(1.0, 4.0),
                      )],
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(5.0)
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Flexible(
                       child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        alignedDropdown: true,
                        child: ... //your other code 
                        ),
```

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you for sharing some information.